# While trying to install miniconda including a bunch of dependencies I think I broke some core stuff in my macOS. How can I undo the damage?

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, conda, homebrew

So I have an M1 MacBook Air. I was curious about the open source project Stable Diffusion and I wanted to try if I could get it to work on my machine.

According to [the requirements](https://github.com/CompVis/stable-diffusion#requirements), first of all I needed to install conda and then when I ran the command `conda env create -f environment.yaml` as it said on the page, I got the response that I didn't have all the necessary dependencies installed. Namely, these:

```
  - cudatoolkit=11.3
  - pip=20.3
  - torchvision=0.12.0
  - python=3.8.5
```

So I tried to install those dependencies, some of which seemed not possible for my machine (mostly cudatoolkit @ version 11.3). But some of the others did work. And then before they installed, they warned me that they would "update" some dependencies that were already installed on my machine. Namely:

```bash
$: conda install -c conda-forge pip

# Skipping over some less relevant output...

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  ca-certificates    pkgs/main::ca-certificates-2022.4.26-~ --> conda-forge::ca-certificates-2022.9.24-h4653dfc_0
  certifi            pkgs/main/osx-arm64::certifi-2022.5.1~ --> conda-forge/noarch::certifi-2022.9.24-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  conda                               4.12.0-py39hca03da5_0 --> 22.9.0-py39hca03da5_0
  openssl              pkgs/main::openssl-1.1.1o-h1a28f6b_0 --> conda-forge::openssl-1.1.1q-ha287fd2_0
  pip                pkgs/main/osx-arm64::pip-21.2.4-py39h~ --> conda-forge/noarch::pip-22.2.2-pyhd8ed1ab_0

$: conda install -c pytorch torchvision

# Again skipping over some less relevant output...

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  certifi            conda-forge/noarch::certifi-2022.9.24~ --> pkgs/main/osx-arm64::certifi-2022.9.24-py39hca03da5_0 None
  openssl            conda-forge::openssl-1.1.1q-ha287fd2_0 --> pkgs/main::openssl-1.1.1q-h1a28f6b_0 None
```

And then the final command that seems to have really messed up my system:

```bash
$: conda install /Users/evert/cuda-gdb-darwin-11.3/python-3.8.5-h85f3143_2_cpython.tar.bz2

Downloading and Extracting Packages
####################################################################################################################################### | 100%
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
Retrieving notices: ...working... done
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/evert/opt/miniconda3/bin/conda", line 12, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'
```

Ever since that last command, I can't run any `conda` command anymore, it will always come back with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'`. And now also my HomeBrew is broken, when I run `brew list` I get:

```bash
$: brew list
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Operation not permitted
Error: The current working directory doesn't exist, cannot proceed.
```

So I'd really like to undo everything I've done. Most importantly, get all the packages that conda "updated" back to what they originally were. I'm hoping that that way HomeBrew will also automatically be fixed. And if possible, also just uninstall every new package that conda installed, because I'm clearly not gonna use it anymore so it's just waisted space now...

But I don't know how, since now both `conda` and `brew` commands exit with errors. Can anybody help me?

Comment: You can't break the core; it's read-only. Mind, neither conda nor brew is core.

Comment: For the error about your cwd being unreachable, just `cd /`

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not 100% sure about this, but after toying around with miniconda some more, it now seems likely to me that it actually never touched any system files.

Because within the miniconda folder, there is a folder called "pkgs". So after finding that folder, I now believe that when it said this:

```
The following packages will be UPDATED:

  ca-certificates    pkgs/main::ca-certificates-2022.4.26-~ --> conda-forge::ca-certificates-2022.9.24-h4653dfc_0
  certifi            pkgs/main/osx-arm64::certifi-2022.5.1~ --> conda-forge/noarch::certifi-2022.9.24-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  conda                               4.12.0-py39hca03da5_0 --> 22.9.0-py39hca03da5_0
  openssl              pkgs/main::openssl-1.1.1o-h1a28f6b_0 --> conda-forge::openssl-1.1.1q-ha287fd2_0
  pip                pkgs/main/osx-arm64::pip-21.2.4-py39h~ --> conda-forge/noarch::pip-22.2.2-pyhd8ed1ab_0
```

It probably literally meant the packages in its own local pkgs folder. And if that's the case then I think I have nothing to worry about.

So my solution in the end has been to install python back to a working version, and then just delete the whole miniconda folder.